# How to query failed job runs in github API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to query all the jobs that failed at a certain stage within my organization, the name of the workflow where the job failed is provision-terraformProvision-provisionStaticAnalysis.yml, so we basically want to know all the jobs that failed at that specific phase.

We want to know how can we pull the information, so far I've completed the following commands, but they don't specifically give me that info:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/5061376665/jobs
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/5061376665/attempts/1
```

I know that the attempts/1 failed for sure, but it doesn't specifically says the stage where it failed.